# Show different site if screen res <1000px

Tags: php, iphone, css, media

I have a client who is on a budget and cannot afford for me to build responsive site using CCS Media Queries, so I want to build a mini site that its liquid and is redirected to when the screen res is < a certain resolution.

What's the best practice?

Kind Regards, Brad

Comment: It's easier to make and maintain a smaller site with media queries than it is to build a completely separate website

Comment: They already have a site built within Wordpress

Comment: using media queries would be better, however if you just want to redirect based on the resolution you have to do it using js, you could put something like `if (1000 > window.screen.width) { window.location = '/smaller-version'; } ` at the very begining of your page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use window.screen to get the resolution of the screen.

[window.screen documentation](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml)

You can check the width and do the redirect accordingly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
        if (window.screen.availablewidth < 1000)
        {
            window.location.href = "http://sizeForSmallRez";
        }
        else
        {
            window.location.href = "http://siteForLargeRez";
        }
</script>
```

​
[Here is a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/A3NnK/5/)  *(this example uses jquery)*

Comment: That link is taking very long to load, and that JS you posted doesn't seem to work.

Comment: jsfiddle.net has been running slow. sorry about that.  I took the jquery document ready check off off the sample above, try that

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.screen.availablewidth < 1000) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/tpdesign/new/mobile/index.html";
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "http://www.trevorpeters.co.uk/tpdesign/new/index.php";
    };​
</script>


This doesn't seem to work

Comment: You need http:// leading the locations  `<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.screen.availablewidth < 1000) 
    { window.location.href = "http://trevorpeters.co.uk/tpdesign/new/mobile/index.html"; } 
        else { window.location.href = "http://trevorpeters.co.uk/tpdesign/new/index.php"; }
            </script> ​`

Answer (score 1):

I would use [**Twitter Bootstrap**](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). I think this is your best bet, especially since it sounds like you are starting from scratch.

If you include this CSS framework, you can very quickly set up a responsive site, that will work for desktop, tablet, and phone. It's not perfect, but it is definitely fast and easy.

Read about the [live grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) that is as easy as adding some classes to your HTML tags, and also about the [responsive design](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive).

Comment: I will look into it cheers! I use the 960 grid system already, this looks similar.

Comment: Yes, it's like an automatically resizing 960 grid system.

Answer (score -1):

Okay I have done some research and found this really simple snippet of code!

```
if (window.screen.width < 1000) {
window.location = 'm.mysite.com';
```

}